# android, textview and MetricAffectingSpan

Tags: android, html

I am trying to extend the html transformation capabilities within Android 4.4.
I am needing to be able to change the text size arbitrarily within a block of text to an absolute value.

So I have a starting block of text sized with an `AbsoluteSizeSpan` like this :

```
ass = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(Integer.valueOf(18), true);
output.setSpan(ass, 0, 255, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Now, when I need to change the size of a word or sentence within this span, I am doing the same again -

```
ass = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(Integer.valueOf(12), true);
output.setSpan(ass, 100, 185, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

However, this is not being taken into account.

Does this mean that this is not possible ?
Do I need to change something in the textview to allow this ?

Comment: Having one `AbsoluteSizeSpan` inside the other just *does not work*.  See my answer for alternative.

Comment: I'd like to understand why, though...

Comment: I stand corrected, I can get these nested spans to work for simple cases back to API 16.  Now I would never do this with text of any complexity because the text layout code is a minefield. Please update your question with a code snippet that fails, also let us know which API you are running.  What might also be helpful are details about the layout of your `TextView`, since the width will determine where line breaks occur, and a lot of weird bugs have shown up around line breaking.  I just need enough info that I can reproduce it.  Perhaps even a screen shot?  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
        AbsoluteSizeSpan ass18 = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(Integer.valueOf(18), true);
        AbsoluteSizeSpan ass12 = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(Integer.valueOf(12), true);
        output.setSpan(ass18, 0, 100, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        output.setSpan(ass12, 100, 185, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        output.setSpan(ass18, 185, 255, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: This would seem to be a workaround, but still not one nested inside another. When processing html tags, this would require keeping a separate list of these and then scanning through them each time there is a new one, to split the definition if one would nest inside the other.  Seems overkill if there is a way to really nest one inside the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution from the example in this link http://www.android--tutorials.com/2016/08/android-absolutesizespan-example.html?m=1

Comment: Yes, @Madhan, your example does indeed use two absolutesizespans, but one is NOT inside of the other.  This is what I am having difficulty doing.